# How to add information like title and description to a link in a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to add title and description to a link that is included in a post.

I'm currently using PHP/Laravel and a package called laravel-notification-channels/facebook-poster.

I can post to my page and I can add links, but I would like to customize the title and the description of the link

Answer (score 0):

Title and Description will be taken from the `og:title` and `og:description` Metatags, just include them in your source.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/#markup